# Stored procedure for return a value based on multiple input

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my stored procedure to return a value based on multiple inputs.But it is not working.

```
USE [E_clinic]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Diseasesp1]

    @id1 nchar(10),
    @id2 nchar(10),
    @id3 nchar(10)

AS

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;


    set @id1=@id1+1
    set @id2=@id2+1
    set @id3=@id3+1

    SELECT [Dname]
    From [dbo].[Disease] AS D
    Left Join [dbo].[Symptom] AS S ON D.[DiseaseID] = S.[DiseaseID]
    Where [SymptomID] = @id1 AND [SymptomID] = @id2 AND [SymptomID] = @id3
END
```

Comment: Define "it's not working"

Comment: you are adding integer value to nchar variables.

Comment: You're also restricting where `SymptomID` is equal to 3 different things so you'll never get any results.

Comment: are you sure is AND the relational operator and not OR?

Comment: Why are you passing in an nchar and then doing math on it? For the question at hand a simple IN would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your procedure like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Diseasesp1]

    @id1 int,
    @id2 int,
    @id3 int

AS

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;


    set @id1=@id1+1
    set @id2=@id2+1
    set @id3=@id3+1

    SELECT [Dname]
    From [dbo].[Disease] AS D
    Left Join [dbo].[Symptom] AS S ON D.[DiseaseID] = S.[DiseaseID]
    AND s.[SymptomID] = @id1 
    Left Join [dbo].[Symptom] AS S1 ON D.[DiseaseID] = S1.[DiseaseID]
    AND s1.[SymptomID] = @id2 
    Left Join [dbo].[Symptom] AS S2 ON D.[DiseaseID] = S2.[DiseaseID]
    AND s2.[SymptomID] = @id3;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use IN for this.

```
Where [SymptomID] in (@id1, @id2, @id3)
```

But I would be significantly concerned that you receive parameters as character data and then do math with them. This is just a bad approach concerning datatypes. What happens when you receive 'a'?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change following things in your stored procedure.
1.@id1,@id2 and @id3 datatypes are nchar(10) but you are try to perform the addition operation with integer(@id1=@id1+1). This is not possible so please change the datatype of @id.
2.In that select statement, where clause you have used the same column with AND logical operator. This is not a correct way to write a SQL select with join query. please use correct where clause with alias name and use correct logical operator and then try..